# Kotlin - coroutines Channels - do they block the calling thread?

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

i know channels is experiemental and we can think of channels as the same as a blocking Queue in java. that being said lets take a look at this simple [block of code](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/channels.html):

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val channel = Channel<Int>()
    GlobalScope.launch {
        for (x in 1..50000) {
            println("from channel $x")
            channel.send(x * x)
        }
    }
    // here we print five received integers:
    runBlocking {repeat(5) { println(channel.receive()) }}
    println("Done!")

}
```

i'd like to know what happens to the rest of the integers.  look at the output from running this:

```
 from channel 1
1
from channel 2
from channel 3
4
9
from channel 4
from channel 5
16
from channel 6
25
Done!
```

why it did not print all 50000 integers ? I have it in a global scope. so this line: `println("from channel $x")` should have been called 50000 times. why did it not ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default capacity of the channel's internal queue is 0. It's a so-called *rendezvous* channel because the producer and the consumer coroutine have to meet to exchange the item. Since you consume only five items, the producer is only able to produce five of them and suspend before delivering the sixth one, at which your entire program completes.

So, here's a modification of your program that prints all 50,000 items:

```
fun main() {
    val channel = Channel<Int>(Channel.UNLIMITED)
    GlobalScope.launch {
        for (x in 1..50000) {
            println("from channel $x")
            channel.send(x * x)
        }
    }
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    println("Done!")
}
```

Note there was no need to consume any of them this time.

Answer (score 4):

send is a suspend function and blocks the coroutine (not thread) if there is no one to receive/dequeue at the other end. This is how back pressure is supported in coroutine world. Your runBlocking repeats only for 5 iterations and your main exits.

Comment: that was key for me that send is a suspend function. thanks!